# Non-split metacylic finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a metacyclic group.

Let's call it a split metacyclic group if it has a cyclic normal subgroup $N$ and a cyclic subgroup $H$ such that $G=HN, H\cap N=1$.

Equivalently, $G\cong C_n\rtimes C_m$ for some $n,m$.

What are the non-split metacyclic groups? The quaternion group $Q_8$ is one example: since every proper subgroup of $Q_8$ contains the unique involution of $Q_8$, $Q_8$ cannot split over proper subgroups, and yet it is metacyclic.

More generally, generalized quaternion groups are metacyclic but they cannot split over proper subgroups because they contain a unique involution, and every proper nontrivial subgroup contains this unique involution.

Looking in the list of metacyclic groups on [groupnames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/MC.html), it seems that there are very few non-split metacyclic groups. Is there perhaps a classification of non-split metacyclic finite groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper [EJC Hempel](https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/144742/2/b20383460_Hempel_E_J_C.pdf) gives a classification of metacyclic groups (Theorem 5.3) and a classification of split metacyclic groups (Theorem 5.4). From here it is possible to derive the classification of non-split metacyclic groups.